# Chaining async with sync actions in Redux for calculating initial state?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Sorry for the long text...
I'm trying to figure out the best way to chain some actions which need to wait for each other for calculating the initial state. Probably **reselect** would help, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to fit it in.
I am using ImmutableJS, but I'll use standard JSON to describe my troubles. Initial state should be like:

```
{
"book": {
"id": 1,
"title": "THE book",
"notes": [
  1,
  2,
  4
]
 },
 "detailedNotes": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "text": "Just a note",
  "categories": [
    "Vital"
  ]
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "text": "Testing",
  "categories": [
    "Vital"
  ]
},
{
  "id": 4,
  "text": "Doodling",
  "categories": [
    "Relevant"
  ]
}
],
"notesByCategory": [
{
  "Vital": [
    1,
    2
   ]
 },
 {
  "Relevant": [
    4
  ]
 }
 ],
 "activeCategory": "Vital"
}
```

**book** and **detailedNotes** are from a GET call (using fetch). **notesByCategory** is calculated by my code (at the moment in the reducer...) and I also need to set the initial value for **activeCategory** as the first calculated category (*Vital* in the example).
Here's the actions.js and reducer.js relevant code:

```
        //in actions
    export function fetchBook(id) {
        return function (dispatch) {
            return fetch('/api/book/' + id)
                .then(json => {
                        dispatch(receiveBook(json));
                        dispatch(fetchDetailedNotes(json['notes']));
                    }
                );
        }
    }
    export function fetchDetailedNotes(ids) {
        return function (dispatch) {
            return fetch('/api/notes/?ids=' + ids.join())
                .then(json => dispatch(receiveDetailedNotes(json)))
        }
    }
    export function receiveDetailedNotes(detailedNotes) {
        return {
            type: RECEIVE_DETAILED_Notes,
            detailedNotes
        }
    }

    //in reducer
    function detailedNotesReducer(state = List(), action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case actions.RECEIVE_DETAILED_NOTES:
                return fromJS(action.detailedNotes);
            default:
                return state
        }
    }
    function notesByCategory(state = List(), action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case actions.RECEIVE_DETAILED_NOTES:
                return extractNotesByCategory(state, action.detailedNotes);
            default:
                return state
        }
    }
```

There's reducer composition also, I omitted it.
Now, I want to set the initial **activeCategory** to the first category, but I have a problem, I have NO idea where to put this. I have to wait first to have the **notesByCategory** part of the state calculated. I feel that this calculation should not be maybe in the reducer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could avoid this by not storing derived data in your state, and instead calculate it using selectors (though you don't necessarily have to use reselect for this).

A selector is really just a function that takes state passed in through mapStateToProps and derives what your container components get as props.

Your selectors have access to the entirety of your store, so in the selector that returns activeCategory you could have some logic that return either `activeCategory` (if not `null`) in the store or some default based on available categories (if `null`).

Treating your store as the 'source of truth' and deriving everything you need from there using selectors has the added benefit of preventing inconsistencies since you can have confidence that the store is correct and independent of other data.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. For some reason I missed selectors when reading about Redux. I actually removed notesByCategory calculation and added a selector for it in the reducer (although it could be located pretty much anywhere I guess). Not sure which is the advantage of using Reselect in this case..

Comment: Hey Drew, actually I still have a problem. The initial value for activeCategory is null, because the joining of notes by category is not processed yet. Kind of a workaround, I use componentWillReceiveProps to wait for the notesByCategory selector to be processed and its corresponding props to be filled. Kind of tricky and ugly?

Comment: Reselect (or something similar) becomes necessary when you start to have a decent amount of logic moved to your selectors and they become somewhat expensive to calculate.With Redux, every action will trigger a recalculation which is often unnecessary if none of the data that your calculations depends on changed. Reselect just memoizes the last input set to avoid recalculation.

Comment: @vicusbass Not sure I understand here, but in your selectors and/or components you should account for the code path for when `activeCategory` is `null` and `detailedNotes` is empty.

Comment: Initially `activeCategory` is null, `detailedNotes` is empty. Then the container is dispatching a request for `detailedNotes` and populates the state using a basic action when data is received. Based on your awesome advice, I am using a selector for joining notes by category. The thing is I want to set the first category from selector as `activeCategory`, but I did not know where would be the best place to dispatch the `setActiveCategory` value based on the selector result, so I am doing it in `componentWillReceiveProps` (because the selector is used as prop in the container). Bad?

Comment: @vicusbass That's not a terrible idea, though another way would be to not actually set `activeCategory` in the store until an action is taken by the user that would set it (such as clicking a button). Instead, just provide a default value in the selector. So when `store.activeCategory === null` then return the default, and just let `activeCategory` continue to be `null`. That way `null` isn't scary - it just means for the selector to take the default.

Comment: Sure, that's the decent way, but I cannot tell which is the default value until the notes joining by category is performed by the selector.. Basically, I have a list of components representing all notes from a category and I navigate between them by changing the active category with dispatch. So when activeCategory is null, I got nothing to display, that's why I need to set an initial activeCategory

Answer (score 0):

Generally, default state should be handled by your reducers. At start you get null state in your reducer and you should provide some 'initial' state.

This is often using via convenience syntax of default parameters (`=List()`) in your case.

Comment: Well, I have default parameters in all my reducers, as you can see in the code example. The problem is that I need to calculate state (and maybe store the calculated state in the store), basically a JOIN. I can calculate state in the reducer, I am actually doing that right now.

Comment: You can easily do some simple synchronous state calculations in the reducer (treating them as initial if incoming state is null). Yet, from your description it starts to feel that you should move the calculations elsewhere, e.g. to action creator or maybe some app init block.

Comment: You're right, at the moment I am using a selector which does this join (cannot tell why I missed the selectors when reading about Redux...)